# Embedde excel file in django project

Tags: javascript, html, django, excel, csv

I want to show excel in my web django priject. csv is also an option.
show the file itself, with option to read and edit inside.
the data for the excel is used in my beb (no need to import a file for that)
anybody knows how??
[it should look like in the img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7liig.png)

all I found is to read data from xl files and import to a web, or the opposite...

Comment: The most general is for the button to be a hyperlink that invokes a Django view which renders the spreadsheet data as an HTML <table>. Or You can javascript library DataTables.